# Ubuntu 13.10 - No Ext2/Ext3 Available

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, filesystem

I need to make a DCP (digital cinema package) for a short film of mine. Digital projectors read ext2 or ext3 formatted drives best, so using a Mac I put Ubuntu on a CD and have been booting up the computer to run off the image.

So when I go into disk and click to format/partition my flash drive I only get the option for ext4. From what I can gather, ext4 isn't recognizable for these projectors. It needs to be ext2 or ext3 but I have absolutely no option to format my flash drive to any of these filesystems.

I'm completely new to Linux so I have no idea how to fix this. Anybody?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

So you boot from an Ubuntu live CD/DVD. When you see Ubuntu welcome screen select `Try Ubuntu`. Wait for the desktop to load.

Now press Ctrl+Alt+T to open Terminal and type here: `sudo gparted`. If it complains about `gparted is not installed` do a

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Note that you will need an internet connection for the `install` procedure.

Open GParted with `sudo gparted`, look in the upper right corner and select your flashdrive.

Now rightclick on the only partition (?) of your flashdrive and select `Unmount` if available. Rightclick again and select `Format to` -> `ext2` or `ext3`.

Now go to `Edit` -> `Apply all operations`. That should be all.

Here is a screenshot to help you:

[image]

[image]